# Monitoring dashboard for a custom application, should also allow custom actions

Tags: linux, centos, monitoring, nagios

I have a custom application, for which I need a dashboard which will monitor the application (show if the application is up/down) and allow an operator to start/stop the application from the monitoring console itself.

I have made simple nagios plugins which will monitor the process. However, I'm stuck as to how to allow an operator to perform an action on the application?

Can you point me to any nagios features which can help, if I'm missing anything? Or, is there any other monitoring tool or dashboard which will allow this?

Comment: apologies, should this go to serverfault instead? can the mods please move it or should I post it again on serverfault?

Comment: Our local Icinga (and Nagios before it) has "extra service notes" links which could probably be abused for that, but right now, i have no clue if they're a standard feature.